# Fresh Rails install won't use version 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I'm trying to install rails for the 1st time.

I can't seem to get it to install beyond Rails 2.2.3.

I have followed the instructions at:
http://rubyonrails.org/download

I downloaded the latest RubyGems and ran 'ruby setup.rb'.

```
$ gem -v  
1.8.11
```

I ran 'gem install rails' and got Rails 2.2.3.

I ran 'gem update' several times and I get:

```
$ gem update  
Updating installed gems  
Updating rails  
Successfully installed rails-2.2.3  
Gems updated: rails  
Installing ri documentation for rails-2.2.3...  
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-2.2.3...
```

I tried gem1.8:

```
$ gem1.8 update  
Updating installed gems  
Updating rails  
Successfully installed rails-2.2.3  
Gems updated: rails  
Installing ri documentation for rails-2.2.3...  
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-2.2.3...  

$ rails -v  
Rails 2.2.3

$ ruby -v  
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i486-linux]
```

I'm using Debian 'unstable' (Wheezy/Sid).

I'm new to rails and don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
I've searched by so far nothing specific to this issue.

I thought the latsted gem would just get Rails 3.1
just as the install docs at the site say?

Any advise much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
gem install rails --pre
```

Comment: Hi .. still no joy  gem install rails --pre  
Successfully installed rails-2.2.3  
1 gem installed  
Installing ri documentation for rails-2.2.3...  
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-2.2.3...

Answer (score 0):

I tried again and it worked fine now.

This time I pointed direct to the
fresh new copy of gem.

All good. Cheers!